# One word to describe doctor, nurse

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there one word that can describe a doctor, nurse, etc.? I've come across "medician" but that's an informal usage that's mostly in science fiction. I want to be able to refer to, essentially a medical professional without using two words.

Comment: How about "medic"?

Comment: Why is important to use only one word?

Answer (score 2):

In the US they're called **practitioners**.

Comment: To preclude confusion, I'd recommend you specifically mention they're called *medical* practitioners.

Comment: The term can refer to persons other than medical practitioners, true. Per Google: "a person actively engaged in an art, discipline, or profession, *especially medicine*." [my emphasis] `patients are treated by skilled practitioners'.  So, although the term isn't limited to medical practitioners, it is most often used in medical contexts. Confusion wouldn't be likely, in context.

Comment: As you like. It's your answer. You have my +1 either way.  But I'm withholding the imaginary additional +1 I would have given you if you had added "medical" ;)

Comment: But the OP wanted a single word "without using two words". I was damned if I did and damned if I didn't :)

Comment: Among practitioners, I have a feeling that *provider* is the nom de jour that encompasses all staff.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, consider [caregiver](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/caregiver)

**caregiver**: An individual, such as a physician, nurse, or social worker, that assists in the identification, prevention, or treatment of an illness or disability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I also had 'medic' suggested, and have decided to go with that

Answer (score 1):

I used "medic" to describe nurses , specifically my daughter an RN, she opined that a mdic is an Emergency Medical Technician or other person who treats outside of the typical hospital. I did some research and found that the military medic is not considered a nurse as well. 
I wanted a one word term to include all of the pros who are working so hard to defeat Corona 19 virus patients.  Robert Fusco

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  Please take a tour of the site to familiarize yourself with the format for answers and comments.  I'm a little confused by your phrasing.